# ExpandableListView Parent/Child Grouping Issue

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am populating an `ExpandableListView` from a sqlite table containing service call information.  I want the parent group to be each unique service site and the child group to contain the call information for all calls at that site.

```
Site A
  Call 1
Site B
  Call 2
```

Instead, I'm getting:

```
Site A
  Call 1
  Call 2
Site B
  Call 1
  Call 2
```

Every service call is showing up under every site.  I've been banging my head against the wall with `ExpandableListViews` for days now and the only code I've been able to use that hasn't generated an onslaught of various errors or the app just crashing is

```
public class Today : ExpandableListActivity
{
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Boards);

        List<IDictionary<string, object>> parent = new List<IDictionary<string,object>>();
        List<IList<IDictionary<string, object>>> child = new List<IList<IDictionary<string,object>>>();

        External inst = new External();
        var connection = inst.conn();
        var c = connection.CreateCommand();
        c.CommandText = "Select Distinct Store || ' ' || City || ', ' || State From Calls";
        connection.Open();
        SqliteDataReader dr = c.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows)
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Dictionary<string, object> pItem = new Dictionary<string,object>();
                pItem.Add("Store", dr[0].ToString());
                parent.Add(pItem);
            }
       dr.Close();
       int cnt = parent.Count();

       if (cnt > 0)
       {
           List<IDictionary<string, object>> children = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();
           foreach(IDictionary<string, object> d in parent)
           {
               foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> k in d)
               {
                   var store = k.Value.ToString().Substring(0, k.Value.ToString().IndexOf(" "));
                   c.CommandText = "Select CallNumber || ' ' || Description From Calls Where Store = '" + store + "'";
                   dr = c.ExecuteReader();
                   while (dr.Read())
                   {
                       Dictionary<string, object> childItem = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                       childItem.Add("Call", dr[0].ToString());
                       children.Add(childItem);
                   }
                   dr.Close();
                   child.Add(children);
               }

           }              
       }
       ExpandableListView view = (ExpandableListView)FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.List);
       IExpandableListAdapter adapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(this, parent, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, new string[] { "Store", "Call" }, new int[] { Android.Resource.Id.Text1, Android.Resource.Id.Text2 }, child, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem2, new string[] { "Store", "Call" }, new int[] { Android.Resource.Id.Text1, Android.Resource.Id.Text2 });
       view.SetAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the childItem to the same List (children) and then adding this list more than once on child.

You must create a `List<List<>>` for every group on the ExpandableListView